# Can I use an Environment variable based location for Spring FileSystemResource?

Tags: java, spring

I have a requirement to have all our properties files be stored in a directory. The location of this directory should be stored in a system environment variable. In my application context I will need to access this environment variable to create the FileSystemResource bean. Here is an example of what I would normally have:

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <bean class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource">
            <constructor-arg>
                <value>myprops.properties</value>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Instead I will need to have it be something like

```
<value>${prop_file_location}/myprops.properties</value>
```

Where prop file location is an environment variable. Does anyone know an easy way of doing this?

I am using spring 2.5.6 and java 1.6

Comment: I guess I could use the System.getEnv(String envName) to return the value. But I am not sure if you can call that method in the application context?

Comment: [`@PropertySources` in Spring 4](http://www.jayway.com/2014/02/16/spring-propertysource/) gives you a java-based config way to do this: `@Configuration
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("default.properties"),
    @PropertySource(value = "file:${CONF_DIR}/optional-override.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
}
public class ApplicationConfig {
}`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## UPDATE

We later upgraded to Spring 3.0.X and we were able to take advantage of the spring expression language. Our approach simplified from three beans to the following snippet:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
        <value>classpath:defaults.properties</value>
        <value>file:/a/defined/location/project.properties</value>
        <value>file:${AN_ENV_CONFIGURED_DIR}/project.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>

  <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
  <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
  <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
</bean>
```

This allowed us to have either a development (the first defaults) statically well known location, or a deployed location configured via env variables. The configurer processes these in order (i.e. the deployed takes precedence over the defaults).

## OLD

I ended up going with a non programmatic approach. I used a MethodInvoker to retrieve the environment value. I was able to then pass that into the FileSystemResource.

```
<bean id="configPath" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean" >
    <property name="targetClass" value="java.lang.String" />
    <property name="staticMethod" value="java.lang.System.getenv" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>NAME_OF_VARIABLE</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: what is the ${AN_ENV_CONFIGURED_DIR} ?

Comment: Spring EL. just a property or environment variable (assuming your properiesplaceholderconfigurer is set to search environment variables.

Comment: i tried your solution and it doesn't work, i made a new environment variable that contains the path of specific property file. i have two questions 1. can you please put the value of the environment variable and how you defined it in environment variables ? second question is that the value of the environment variable is getting replaced during runtime or compiled time ? and how to know that the value is replaced correctly ?

Comment: Setting an environment variable is OS specific. I would recommend looking up how to setup environment variables via google. In the top example I show how to configure the PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer. Most importantly is the <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />. If you want more specific details refer to the spring documentation: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#new-feature-el

Comment: You specified three values in the list. At runtime, if spring finds all the three properties files specified in the values tag, which one it will choose? what is the precedence order?

Answer (score 3):

while I note that the question required 2.5.x, it's worth pointing out that Spring 3's EL support (available since Nov 2009) would've made short work of this sort of thing

```
@Value("#{ systemProperties['user.home'] }") 
private String userHome ;
```

or

```
<property name = "userHome" value ="#{ systemProperties['user.home'] }"/>
```

Comment: Yea we ended up upgrading to Spring 3.0.X. I updated my final solution with the approach that we took.

Answer (score 1):

You could always extend the FileSystemResource  (i.e. PropertiesFileResource) that would initialize itself by taking prepending the property file location system property to the file path.

Comment: I thought about doing this, but I had three separate projects that I needed to do the same thing with. Figured a snippet of xml was better than implementing the same class 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring.Net we have got the [IVariableSource](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-variablesource) interface and [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-factory-placeholderconfigurer) which are able to retrieve values from environment variables. Maybe there is something similar in the Spring Framework for Java?

**Edit:** I *think* I found the corresponding java bean which is named PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer as well [in the java docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html#setSystemPropertiesMode(int)).

Answer (score 0):

Example:

Start you app with -DDA_HOME=c:\temp

c:\temp must contain directory called "config"

In c:\temp\config you have file app.properties (for example)

Extend the Spring loader:

```
public class Loader extends org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer{

    private String appHome;

    public void setAppHome(String appHome) {
        this.appHome = appHome;
    }

    @Override
    public void setLocation(Resource location) {
        if(appHome==null){
            throw new RuntimeException("You must specify VM property DA_HOME, this directory must contain " +
                    "another directory, called config, inside the config directory app.properties " +
                    "file must be found with the configuration properties");
        }
        String configurationDirectory = appHome + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "config";
        String fileName = location.getFilename();
        Resource file = new FileSystemResource( configurationDirectory + System.getProperty("file.separator")+ fileName);
        super.setLocation(file);
    }
}
```

Specify the new loader and its configuration base:

```
    <bean id="placeholderConfig"    class="your.Loader">
        <property name="appHome" value="#{systemProperties['DA_HOME']}"/>
        <property name="location" value="app.properties" />
    </bean>
```