# Spring load context placeholder external property file from environment variable

Tags: spring, properties

I am using java Spring 3.x

I wants to load context place holder property file from OS environment variable.
Following is my code

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:#{ systemProperties['RESOURCE_PATH']}/jdbc.properties,
```

where RESOURCE_PATH is my linux environment variable but i am getting file not found exception.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: When you get the exception I'm sure it's also telling you where exactly Spring was looking i.e. the fully resolved path to the file. Is that correct? Does the Java process have access to that file? Also, don't you need `file://` instead of just `file:`? You may also omit that I believe.

Comment: maybe duplicated of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841857/can-i-use-an-environment-variable-based-location-for-spring-filesystemresource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System properties are Java system properties, not OS. Try using the variable `systemEnvironment` instead.