# How to load dynamic properties file based on the java argument using spring

Tags: spring

I am using spring 3.2. I have different properties file like `a.properties, b.properties, c.properties`. Now in my spring i am using something like

```
public class FtpInbound {

    private static final String XML_CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION = "springIntegration/ftp-inbound-context.xml";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GenericXmlApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        context.load(XML_CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION);
        context.refresh();

    } //end of main()

} //end of class Main
```

In xml i am using something like

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/spring/ftp/ftp.properties"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="pk.training.basitMahmood.springIntegration.ftp"/>
```

Now i want that if user passes a as an argument to main() method then it will become

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/spring/ftp/a.properties"/>
```

If user passes b to main() argument, then it will become

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/spring/ftp/b.properties"/>
```

and so on..

How can i do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use an environment variable? e.g. as in this question:

[Can I use an Environment variable based location for Spring FileSystemResource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841857/can-i-use-an-environment-variable-based-location-for-spring-filesystemresource)