# Spring Properties from Docker Environment Variables

Tags: java, spring, docker

I'm trying to switch between config files inside a docker container using environment variables for my Spring 3.2.16 application.

In my application context I have two profiles that load property files, the one I dev against (which works 100%) looks like this:

```
<beans profile="dev">
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/dev.properties" />
</beans>
```

When packaging the application in a container, there's not much to it, here's my Docker file:

```
FROM jetty
MAINTAINER Jan Vladimir Mostert "me@example.com"

ADD ./target/ROOT.war /var/lib/jetty/webapps/ROOT.war

EXPOSE 8080
```

When running it, notice the `-e` flag to set the environment variable:

```
docker run --name='_______' -d -p 8000:8080 --link rabbitmq:rabbitmq -e ENV=test _________________
```

When running it in `test`, `prod`, `...`, the default profile kicks in which I've setup as `cloud`. This works as well:

```
<beans profile="cloud">
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/test.properties" />
</beans>
```

Now I want to swap out that `test.properties` to pick up the config file from an environment variable.

I've tried using `systemProperties`, but it doesn't work:

```
    <beans profile="cloud">
        <context:property-placeholder 
            location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/#{systemProperties['ENV']}.properties" />
    </beans>
```

I've tried using `systemEnvironment` which doesn't work either:

```
<beans profile="cloud">
    <context:property-placeholder 
        location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/#{systemEnvironment['ENV']}.properties" />
</beans>
```

Entering the container with:

```
docker exec -ti _______ bash
```

and running

```
echo $ENV
```

prints

> test

The environment variable is set correctly, what is the correct way of getting that variable into my `applicationContext.xml`?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744663/how-to-inject-environmental-variables-inside-spring-xml-configuration

Comment: Wow, that's pretty simple, just `${ENV}` and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to

```
<beans profile="cloud">
    <context:property-placeholder 
        location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/${ENV}.properties" />
</beans>
```

magically makes it work.