# Loading both mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml and applicationContext.xml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I am using Spring 3 MVC.
I have both mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml and applicationContext.xml.
But applicationContext.xml is not loading only mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml is loading.

Any problem with my configuration?

### web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"  
    version="2.5">  
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>  
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
         </init-param>  
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
    </servlet>  

    <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>  
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
        <param-value>classpath:spring/extendedContext.xml</param-value>  
    </context-param>  

    <listener>  
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>  
    </listener>  
</web-app>
```

Comment: If the name is `applicationContext.xml`, then that would be loaded by default. You don't need a `contextConfigLocation` for that.

Comment: Rohit, i edited my question. it is not applicationContext.xml.

Comment: Rohit, do i need to do any other config?

Comment: No that seems fine to me. May be someone more experienced in Spring will take a look.

Comment: Is applicationContext.xml at path: /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml? If so it would take it by default without specifying contextconfiglocation.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler configuration is to use the `import` tag in dispatcher servlet XML:

```
<import resource="classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml" />
```

It is documented here section 3.2.2.1:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/beans.html

Here is another SO question/answer around this topic:

[ContextLoaderListener or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016122/contextloaderlistener-or-not)

Comment: Note that this is a completely different configuration than using a ContextLoaderListener.

Comment: Kevin, then shall i remoe ContextLoaderListener ?

Comment: Yes, you remove it and import in the dispatcher servlet xml instead.

Comment: You don't need a ContextLoaderListener if your configuration file name is ApplicationContext and the file location is the default location. else you need to use the ContextLoaderListener and provide the exact location

Comment: I have overridden ContextLoaderListener. If i dont use then i loose some functionlality..

Comment: your `<listener-class>` in web.xml is not the normal one then?

Comment: I have overridden ContextLoaderListener to resolve some property file names. Ex: i have a property file names as appprop-{env}.props. In Web.xml i give <context-param>
  <param-name>env</param-name>
  <param-value>dev/uat/prod</param-value>
 </context-param>. overridden contextloader listener would replace {env} with value. Now how can i resolve it if i dont use context loader lister?

Comment: have you ever used `<context:property-placeholder location="..." />`? I have typically managed this outside of spring: you put a standard name as the location for the `property-placeholder`, such as my-app.properties, and then you create a symbolic link from your environment specific name to the standard name. This allows you to switch out properties by updating a symlink rather than a code launch.

Comment: If you don't like the symlink approach, you can use environment variables in your location as well, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841857/can-i-use-an-environment-variable-based-location-for-spring-filesystemresource.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to Load **all the context files using ContextLoader separated by comma**.

```
 <web-app>  
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>  
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>  
   </servlet-mapping>

   <context-param>  
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
        <param-value>classpath:spring/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml, 
                 classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml,
                 classpath:spring/extendedContext.xml
       </param-value>  
   </context-param>  

   <listener>  
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>  
   </listener>
</web-app>
```