# Spring Websocket : receiving nothing from SimpMessagingTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, websocket

I'm currently using Websockets in a Spring-MVC webapp to send notifications to spring-security-authenticated users at any time. The point is to notify users without any page refresh or user interaction (like Facebook does for example).

Therefore, I'm using Spring's `SimpMessagingTemplate`

It looks (as seen in the browser console) like the client subscribes correctly, and that the `SimpMessagingTemplate` actually sends a message (debugging the Spring code shows a happy flow happening, `sent == true` etc). However, nothing happens at client-side - which is the issue.

After hours of re-reading the reference, other Stackoverflow posts etc (which do the same thing as here.. But seem to work !), I can't find an appropriate solution. The only difference is that I have a duplicated websocket configuration, which might be the cause of my troubles, but that I cannot get rid of (more on that hereunder : see `dispatcher-servlet.xml` and `applicationContext.xml`).

Client-side, I subscribe like this :

```
<script>
    var socket = new SockJS('/stomp');
    var client = Stomp.over(socket);

    client.connect({}, function(s) {
            client.subscribe('/user/queue/notify', function (msg) {
            alert('SHOULD SEE THIS.. BUT DOES NOT WORK');
            console.log("SHOULD SEE THIS.. BUT DOES NOT WORK");
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have a controller that sends a simple message to user "niilzon" every 10 seconds (this is just a simple test ofcourse)

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class WebsocketTestController {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
    public void sendStuff() {
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser("niilzon", "/queue/notify", "SEEING THIS WOULD BE GREAT");
    }

}
```

Browser console, after the "niilzon" user logged in :

```
<<< CONNECTED
version:1.1
heart-beat:0,0
user-name:niilzon

connected to server undefined
>>> SUBSCRIBE
id:sub-0
destination:/user/queue/notify
```

And here is the XML configuration :

dispatcher-servlet.xml :

```
<!-- TODO this is duplicated in applicationContext !
 If removing the websocket tag in dispatcher-servlet : 404 when client tries to connect to /stomp
 If removing the websocket tag in applicationContext : cannot autowire SimpMessagingTemplate in WebsocketTestController
 -->
<websocket:message-broker>
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/stomp">
        <websocket:sockjs/>
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic,/queue"/>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

applicationContext.xml :

```
<websocket:message-broker>
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/stomp">
        <websocket:sockjs/>
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic,/queue"/>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

As described in `dispatcher-servlet.xml`, the websocket configuration is duplicated in `applicationContext.xml`. 
If I remove the tag in `dispatcher-servlet.xml`, the client gets a 404 when trying to connect. 
If I remove the tag in `applicationContext.xml`, the `SimpMessagingTemplate` cannot be autowired in `WebsocketTestController`.

Could the configuration duplication be part of the issue ? That's the only lead I have left, but I am unable to fix it.
An important thing to note is that some other config tags are duplicated between the 2 xml files. Here are ALL the duplications between the 2 config files, put next to each other (+ the websocket config as seen above) :

```
<import resource="spring-security.xml"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.beatboxnow.**"/>
<tx:annotation-driven />
<!-- TODO merge / inherit contexts instead of this dupe ? How ? same with tx:annotationDriven -->
<cache:annotation-driven />
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache"/>
</bean>
<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
    <property name="shared" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

There are no issues with the rest of the webapp, which has alot of views, controllers, services, repositories etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Well I think I found the solution, which is to remove all the duplicates and import applicationContext.xml in the dispatcherServlet. I'll post a proper answer as soon as I'm sure of this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to this StackOverflow post here [Loading both mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml and applicationContext.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534763/loading-both-mvc-dispatcher-servlet-xml-and-applicationcontext-xml), I managed to merge the duplicates in the `dispatcher-servlet` and `applicationContext` XML's.

The trick was simply to import the `applicationContext` in the `dispatcher-servlet` like this :

```
<import resource="applicationContext.xml" />
```

, and to remove all the duplicates (not touching any tag in `applicationContext.xml` obviously).

I had this partial configuration duplication issue hanging since the beginning of this project and planned to remove it later on - tried the import at that time but I did not manage to do it back then.
Now this Websocket issue forced me to try it again (duplicating was not blocking before), and surprisingly it worked perfectly, I suppose that I made a silly mistake during the first try, since it was in fact rather trivial :)

Comment: Well I can't accept my own answer for 2 days, but this is indeed solved, the rest of the webapp has no regression at all. Aaaah yeaah now let's have some fun with those Websockets !!!! :)