# How Spring replacing the ${} with environment variable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, spring-bean

**Here is my XML bean configuration**

```
<beans:bean class="com.utils.OverridingPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="overridingSource" value="file:${config_path}/config.properties"/>
    <beans:property name="locations" value="classpath*:META-INF/*-config.properties" />
</beans:bean>
```

Below is my  OverridingPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer

```
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;

public class OverridingPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer implements InitializingBean, ApplicationContextAware {

    protected ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    protected Resource overridingSource;

    public void setOverridingSource(Resource overridingSource) {
        this.overridingSource = overridingSource;
    }
    .......
```

**Here is my tomcat context whhich is injecting `config_path` with value as `C:/myFolder` under environment variable.**

```
<Environment name="config_path" override="false" type="java.lang.String" value="C:/myFolder"></Environment>
```

When I start my server I see `setOverridingSource()` method is called under `OverridingPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`   and overridingSource property is resolved 
to  `C:/myFolder` instead of `config_path`. I am not sure how spring is replacing placeholder `config_path` with actual value from environment value set through web server ?

I understand BeanFactoryProcessor can do it for other spring beans. But my doubt here is `OverridingPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` in itself  is a BeanFactoryProcessor . So who is resolving place holder value in that ?

**I am using spring 4.2**

Answer (score 0):

Spring 3 onwards , it will be done automatically under class `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` if environment variable is set . See [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html)

> Any local properties (e.g. those added via
>   PropertiesLoaderSupport.setProperties(java.util.Properties),
>   PropertiesLoaderSupport.setLocations(org.springframework.core.io.Resource...)
>   et al.) are added as a PropertySource. Search precedence of local
>   properties is based on the value of the localOverride property, which
>   is by default false meaning that local properties are to be searched
>   last, after all environment property sources.

Also See [Can I use an Environment variable based location for Spring FileSystemResource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841857/can-i-use-an-environment-variable-based-location-for-spring-filesystemresource/1843010#1843010)